# Node.js Passport Authentication - log is not defined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am working on user login page with node.js, passport, and postgres. I thought I got user authentication working. However, when I try to change pages I get this error and my server won't load anything. `{"message":"log is not defined","error":{}}`. I have been stuck on this error for hours now and can't figure out what is causing it. I am guessing that the session is somehow getting messed up but I could be wrong. I am hoping someone knows the answer. Here is my relevant code.

I am extremely new to web development and because of that I am sure it is probably something simple I am missing.

**main-config.js**

```
(function(appConfig) {

'use strict';

// *** main dependencies *** //
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
const passport = require('passport');

// *** view folders *** //
const viewFolders = [
path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views')
];

// *** load environment variables *** //
require('dotenv').config();

appConfig.init = function(app, express) {

// *** view engine *** //
nunjucks.configure(viewFolders, {
  express: app,
  autoescape: true
});
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// *** app middleware *** //
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'anything',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'client')));

  };

})(module.exports);
```

**local.js**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
  },
  (username, password, done) => {
  return db.one("SELECT * " +
    "FROM Users " +
    "WHERE Email=$1", [username])
  .then((result)=> {
    return done(null, result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    return done(null, false, {message:'Wrong user name or password'});
  });
}));
```

**passport.js**

```
module.exports = () => {

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.userid);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=>{
    log.debug("deserialize ", id);
    db.one("SELECT * FROM User " +
            "WHERE user_id = $1", id)
    .then((user)=>{
      done(null, user);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      done(new Error(`User with the id ${id} does not exist`));
    })
  });
};
```

**auth.js**

```
router.post('/login', authHelpers.loginRedirect, (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) { handleResponse(res, 500, 'error'); }
    if (!user) {
      console.log("User Not Found");
      handleResponse(res, 404, 'User not found');
    }
    if (user) {
      req.logIn(user, function (err) {
        if (err) { handleResponse(res, 500, 'error'); }
        handleResponse(res, 200, 'success');
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a clear error message - `log` is not defined in the following line in passport

```
log.debug("deserialize ", id);
```

Define your log object with a logger and everything should be good. Or just remove it for now.

Comment: Man, thank you for that fix. I can't believe I missed that. I was looking for something more complicated, lol. Anyway, greatly appreciated.

Comment: We all have our moments! Going forward I recommend you find yourself a good [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to catch these perspective issues.